# Caching web services data using Java Spring

Tags: java, json, spring, web-services, spring-mvc

What required:
We are having a web project calling web services made in Java Spring MVC.
Every-time page loads that API made a request and response generates which takes time in loading data and counts x read operations.
So, caching in browser is required to avoid duplicate data - the data that already load once in a browser.

What I'm expecting:

1. Browser made a request via web services and generates JSON response in return.
2. That response should be cached by browser.
3. Now, whenever next request generates over same URL the server returns token - along with updated data - if any change made in data.
   If no change made that should return same token.

Is it possible using Java Spring with any browser side script..?

Comment: Where do you want to cache the data? Server or Client Side? Server side use [ehcache](http://www.ehcache.org/) or [hazelcast](https://hazelcast.com/).  For the client side it depends what you are using an example for [angular is here](https://hackernoon.com/angular-simple-in-memory-cache-service-on-the-ui-with-rxjs-77f167387e39)

Comment: Hello  jojo_Berlin - Thanks! for your response. We are using Polymer-2 in our project. So, using Polymer JS at client side.

Comment: Have a look at [ShallowEtagHeaderFilter](http://www.baeldung.com/etags-for-rest-with-spring)